# Error: use of 'self' in property

Tags: swift

i am new to swift. i am doing the exercise in App Development with swift. The class memberwise initializers and reference.

i don't know how to solve the problem. The question is to write your own initializer without providing default values for everything.

```
class Spaceship {
    let name: String
    var health: Int = 100
    var position: Int = 0

    func moveLeft() {
        position -= 1
    }

    func moveRight() {
        position += 1
    }

    func wasHit() {
        health -= 5
    }

    init(name:String, health:Int, position:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.position = position
    }
}

class Fighter: Spaceship {
    let weapon: String
    var remainingFirePower: Int

    init(weapon:String,remainingFirePower:Int) {
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.remainingFirePower = remainingFirePower
        super.init(name: name, health: health, position: position)
    }

    func fire() {
        if remainingFirePower > 0 {
            remainingFirePower -= 1
        } else {
            print("You have no more fire power.")
        }
    }
}

class ShieldedShip: Fighter {
    var shieldStrength: Int

    override func wasHit() {
        if shieldStrength > 0 {
            shieldStrength -= 5
        } else {
            super.wasHit()
        }
    }
    init(shieldStrength:Int, weapon:String, remainingFirePower:Int){
        self.shieldStrength = shieldStrength
        super.init(weapon:weapon, remainingFirePower:remainingFirePower)
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is a terrible place to debug your small program. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ What steps have you taken to solve this yourself?

Comment: the program works perfectly when i give values to the name, health and position. i am wondering is there other methods to solve the program rather than this. As the question is to write your own initializer without providing default values for everything.

Comment: If it works perfectly, then you have a way to start figuring out where it stops working perfectly. Work from the known to the unknown, testing your assertions as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Read about `optional` types. You can write:

```
let name: String?
var health: Int?
var position: Int?
```

[Link for optional types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: I doubt this is what the OP was actually asking. The error occurs on this line: `super.init(name: name, health: health, position: position)`. Hence, clarifications should be made to the question

Answer (score 0):

Here id what you want

```
init(name:String = "ship", health:Int = 100, position:Int = 0) {
    self.name = name
    self.health = health
    self.position = position
}
```

Basically, you want to set default value like this and if you just want to init it with default values, pass NOTHING into this function, like this

```
super.init()
```

Comment: so, i need to give a value to this parameters in the init section first at least?i don't understand what the question means by writing my own initializer

Comment: @sam Yes. If you want to have a default value for your `Spaceship` class' init method, you have to do it there like what I did. And then when you call this init method, you can either pass in data to override the default value, or just provide no input to use default values